# Best way to construct a read-only, empty List?

Tags: java, java-6

I'm creating an immutable representation of an "event" in my system, and thus for lists of owners passed in the constructor, I'd like to take a read only view of them.  Further, if they pass in `null` for the list, I'd like to make a read-only empty list in that case.

Now, since `Collections.unmodifiableList` balks at `null`, I currently have this:

```
userOwners_ = Collections.unmodifiableList(userOwners != null 
                                           ? userOwners 
                                           : new ArrayList<String>(0));
```

But that seems a bit ugly and inefficient.  Is there a more elegant way to do this in Java?

Comment: Empty unmodifiable list should be final static (like ENUM), I would never create new object of unmodifiable empty list every time.

Comment: I may not understand your concern, but is there a reason not to use [Collections.emptyList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()) ?

Comment: Thanks folks for all your input, I'm coming from the C# land and trying to shift into Java style/practices so all the input has been great and I've tried to up-vote everyone and wish I could pick multiple answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equally ugly, but marginally more efficient answer would be

```
userOwners_ = userOwners != null ? 
                  Collections.unmodifiableList(userOwners) :
                  Collections.emptyList();
```

However there are a couple of other things to observe.

1. It appears that at some point, someone has decided to use `null` to represent an empty list.  That is poor design ... and results in the need for special handling.  Better to set it to either a new list, or `emptyList()` if you know the list is always empty.
2. If you haven't consciously decided that `null` is the way to represent an empty list, then that `null` is "unexpected" and you should juts let it throw an NPE so you can track down and fix the cause.  (It could be a variable that you have assumed is initialized elsewhere ... but isn't.  That's a bug.)
3. There is some confusion about whether you want a "read-only" list or an "immutable" list:

   - The `unmodifiableList()` method gives you a list that you cannot modify; i.e. it is "read only".  But the original list can still be modified, and those changes will be visible via the "read only" wrapper.
   - If you want an "immutable" list (i.e. one that cannot be changed at all), you need to `clone()` the original list, and then wrap the clone using `unmodifiableList()`.
   - Neither of these will make the elements of the list (the "owner" objects) immutable (if they are not already immutable).
4. The identifier `userOwners_` is a code style violation in the most widely accepted / used Java style guide.

Comment: Hey Stephen, 1) part of original design, I'm just updating code.  3) I did not know that about unmodifiableList(), I had assumed (incorrectly) it was a shallow-copy and not just a wrapper. 4) unfortunately, this is legacy code I'm modifying and that's the style.

Comment: I liked all the answers, but I think yours seemed the most comprehensive, Stephen, thanks to all!

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare - Re 1) and 4) ... you could fix these things.  The fact that the code is legacy doesn't mean that you can't tidy it up / improve it, and if you expect the code to last longer, there's a solid case that you *should* fix it.  OK, 1) and 4) are qualitatively different, but even so ... And in the case of 1) it is important to reverse engineer what the original author's intent was vis-a-vis `null` handling.  Otherwise you risk *hiding* bugs by "making good" `null` values that shouldn't have been there.

Comment: Oh I do agree, at the same time, I'm wary of modifying a mission critical system that currently works and breaking it.  Unfortunately, it doesn't have a good unit-test suite, etc.  I'm trying to bring it up to speed, but I'm wary of accidentally causing an operational failure.  But yes, I will trace it back and see if a null is even possible here.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

`Collections.emptyList()`. But seriously, `null` should NPE.

Comment: This is a modification to legacy code, so I'm not sure if the original author of the service this resides in had intended `null` to be a valid input.  But your point is well taken.  On situations like this, is it considered better style in Java (sorry I come from the C# world so trying to paradigm shift) to throw an argument exception, or let the NPE bubble through on its own?  I would tend to do the former unless Java style tends to prefer the later...

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare `null`s tend to indicate that there is some error. In Java the usual (though by no means exclusive) is to catch errors as early as possible. I was going to give a reference Effective Java, but all I can see is Item 43 on not returning null for collections and example code in Item 39.

Answer (score 1):

The resultant userOwners_ will still be mutable - any changes to userOwners will be part of userOwners_.

The right way to do this if you really want that member variable to be immutable:

```
private final List<String> userOwners;

public MyObject(List<String> userOwners){
  this.userOwners = userOwners != null ? Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>(userOwners)) : Collections.emptyList();
}
```

As a minor point, your member variable naming isn't following Java style guidelines (userOwners_ is strange to those of us who read Java code on a regular basis)

To expand on what another poster wrote:  Think really, really hard before you accept a null input to a public method (without throwing NPE).  This sort of behavior can hide bugs - much better to fail fast and force the caller to think about what they are doing.

Comment: But the OP wants a read-only list, not an immutable one.  Now this is a fine distinction ... but nevertheless that's why there are two distinct terms.

Comment: @StephenC actually, the author wrote that they were creating "creating an immutable representation of an "event"".  I think my advice on this point still stands, b/c what they have done so far is absolutely *not* immutable.

Comment: Yes, I had a bad assumption about unmodifiableList being a shallow copy, not just a wrapper.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way would be using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
this.userOwners = ImmutableList.copyOf(Preconditions.checkNotNull(userOwners));
```

Like tackline's answer, this also throws an exception rather than silently translating null into the empty list.

Unlike the other answers here, using `ImmutableList.copyOf()` ensures that the caller can't pass you a list that they can later mutate.